# Can we use Google cloud function to convert xls file to csv

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gmail-api

I am new to google cloud functions. My requirement is to trigger cloud function on receiving a gmail and convert the xls attachment from the email to csv.
Can we do using GCP.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Very shortly - that is possible as far as I know.

But.

You might found that in order to automate this task in a reliable, robust and self-healing way, it may be necessary to use half a dozen cloud functions, pubsub topics, maybe a cloud storage, maybe a firestore collection, security manager, customer service account with relevant IAM permissions, and so on. Maybe more than a dozen or two dozens of different GCP resources. And, obviously, those cloud functions are to be developed (I mean the code is to be developed). All together that may be not a very easy or quick to implement.

At the same time, I personally saw (and contributed to a development of) a functional component, based on cloud functions, which together did exactly what you would like to achieve. And that was in production.